# postgres was not the same version as pg_ctl in PostgreSQL 12

Tags: 20.04, postgresql

As per the log files, I am getting the below errors.

*The program "postgres" was found by "/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl"
but was not the same version as pg_ctl.
Check your installation.*

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.
Executed the following commands:

**/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres --version**

```
postgres (PostgreSQL) 12.16 (Ubuntu 12.16-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
```

**/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl --version**

```
pg_ctl (PostgreSQL) 12.15 (Ubuntu 12.15-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
```

Do I need to update or perform some tasks as this has rendered my DB Server useless and I have some databases which I am not able to access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not restart my PostgreSQL Server, I decided to copy the data files in `/etc/postgresql/12/main` to another server and check if it worked.

While trying to test this on a new Server, I installed the same version of PostgreSQL 12 and then tried checking the version info of the **pg_ctl** and **postgres**.

```
postgres (PostgreSQL) 12.16 (Ubuntu 12.16-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)

pg_ctl (PostgreSQL) 12.16 (Ubuntu 12.16-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
```

I was surprised the versions were the same, unlike in my present server. So, I copied the binary files from my new server to my old one from the location `/var/lib/postgresql/12`.

Once this was done, my PostgreSQL started without any issues or complaints. I know this may not be the best approach, but it worked and allowed me to take a dump of the data.

However, the question remains about how the version changed for the old server.